Help improving arrows in tikz illustration
I have made the following figure, but I think the curved arrows both look weird and they don't point directly at the elements I want them to point at. I was hoping someone could help make the arrows better and just the figure more pretty.
I have the following code:
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
% while i loop
\node[draw, rectangle](v) at (0,0){\texttt{v = [Filter$_0$(net=[], output=[$\dots$]), Filter$_1$($\dots$)],$\dots$}} ; 
\node[draw=none](while)  at (-4.1, 1.5)[]{\texttt{While-loop (i)}}; 
\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (-3,1) -- (-3,0.4);
% bøjet linje
\draw[very thick] (-3,-0.4) -- (-3,-1.2);
\draw[very thick,arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}](-3.02,-1.2)--(-1.3,-1.2); 
% pil ved is_redundant 
\node[draw=none] at (0.4, -1.5){\texttt{While-loop (j)}}; 
\node[draw, rectangle] at (3.2,-2.2){\texttt{is\_redundant(std\_comp=[2,5,8], Filter$_0$)}};
\node[draw=none] at (9, -3){\texttt{j  = j+1}}; 
% pile til true og false
%comparator pil
\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4,-1.7) -- (4,-2);
%false pil
\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4,-2.7) -- (3,-3.5);
%true pil
\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4.2,-2.7) -- (5.2,-3.5);
%true of false
\node[draw=none] at (2.8,-3.7){\texttt{False}};
%True text
\node[draw=none] at (5.4,-3.7){\texttt{True}};
%bøjet pil
\draw[-Latex] (6,-3.7)[xshift=19em] to[ bend right] (-3.2,-2);
%pil under false
\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (2.8,-4.3) -- (2.8,-4.5);
%add() sectuin
\node[draw, rectangle] at (2.8, -5){\texttt{v = v+[add(std\_comp(j),v[i])]}};
%pil fra v = v+...
\draw [black]   (6.06,-5) to[out=0,in=-90] (8, -2.6);
%pil fra std_comp 8
\draw[-Latex] (5,-2)[xshift=12em] to[ bend right] (0,0.5);
\node[draw=none] at (8.5,0){\texttt{i = i+1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Illustration af \texttt{extend()}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}

With the following output

I know the code is ugly, but when I used [above=of v], with the coordinates, I felt the distance was to big and did everything manually.

Have a look at the library positionning and 5 Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains

Here is a way to do it. Keys, file names used below in bold:

use a main document, class e.g. article (tikzArrows-main.tex)
use a separate file for each Tikz drawing, class standalone (tikzArrows-MS.tex)

1. Your main document
Assume, the compile tikzArrows-MS.pdf (!) of your drawing already exists. Then all you do is:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 Here comes your text \dots
 
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tikzArrows-MS}
  \caption{Illustration af \texttt{extend()}}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}


2. Your Tikz drawing
I tried to reduce visual noise from your approach by using straight lines only. If you want to bend, try replacing -- by to[out=,in=] and specify angles. Discard bend.

I tried keeping your code, with some adjustments:

introduce some styles to simplify code
I'd place nodes first, draw connections later, i.e. won't mix it
instead of deleting all \draw from your code, I kept them commented-out

The connections I did this way:

starting simple, connect directly first, e.g.: \draw[->] (while)     -- (v);
later I used polar notation to shift anchor points by visual trial&error, e.g.: \draw[->] (while.341)    -- (v.175);
some conections could need a rectangular bend, e.g.: \draw[->] (whileJ.east) -| (red); (start drawing horizontally, then vertically)
some needed an intermediary point, which I addressed as relative coordinate, e.g.: \draw[->] (comp.west) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- (red.west);
spells out: start at left, move -1.5 to the left, then upwards and horizontally

One sophistication is left:

starts at node (T)
moves 2.5 to the right
then up and right towards node (red.east), i.e. its right side
IN BETWEEN put a node (note the missing \ )
relevant part is pos=0.25 : place its west anchor on 1/4 of the path between the intermediare point and (red.east)
and delete the nodes from your original code (they now found a better place)

\draw[->] (T)           -- ++(2.5,0) 
                        |- node[txt,anchor=west,pos=.25,xshift=.5em]{j = j + 1} 
                           (red.east);

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tt/.style={font={\ttfamily}},   % font
    txt/.style={draw=none,tt},      % for text
    box/.style={draw,tt},           % text with a frame
    >={Stealth},
]
% ~~~ let's place the nodes, first ~~~~~~~~~
% while i loop
\node[txt](while)   at (-4.1, 1.5)[]{While-loop (i)}; 
\node[box](v)       at (0,0){v = [Filter$_0$(net=[], output=[$\dots$]),
                                  Filter$_1$($\dots$)],$\dots$} ; 
    %\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (-3,1) -- (-3,0.4);
% bøjet linje
    %\draw[very thick] (-3,-0.4) -- (-3,-1.2);
    %\draw[very thick,arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}](-3.02,-1.2)--(-1.3,-1.2); 
% pil ved is_redundant 
\node[txt] (whileJ) at (0.4, -1.5){While-loop (j)}; 
\node[box] (red)    at (3.2,-2.2){is\_redundant(std\_comp=[2,5,8], Filter$_0$)};
%\node[txt]             at (9, -3){j  = j+1}; 
% pile til true og false
%comparator pil
    %\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4,-1.7) -- (4,-2);
%false pil
    %\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4,-2.7) -- (3,-3.5);
%true pil
    %\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (4.2,-2.7) -- (5.2,-3.5);
%true of false
\node[txt]  (F)     at (2.8,-3.7){False};
%True text
\node[txt]  (T)     at (5.4,-3.7){True};
%bøjet pil
    %\draw[-Latex] (6,-3.7)[xshift=19em] to[ bend right] (-3.2,-2);
%pil under false
    %\draw [arrows = {-Latex[width=10pt, length=10pt]}] (2.8,-4.3) -- (2.8,-4.5);
%add() sectuin
\node[box]  (comp)  at (2.8, -5){v = v+[add(std\_comp(j),v[i])]};
%pil fra v = v+...
    %\draw [black]   (6.06,-5) to[out=0,in=-90] (8, -2.6);
%pil fra std_comp 8
    %\draw[-Latex] (5,-2)[xshift=12em] to[ bend right] (0,0.5);
%\node[txt]             at (8.5,0){i = i+1};

% ~~~ now all connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\draw[->] (while.341)   -- (v.175);
\draw[->] (v.185)       |- (whileJ.west);
\draw[->] (whileJ.east) -| (red);
\draw[->] (red)         -- (T);
\draw[->] (red)         -- (F);
\draw[->] (F)           -- (comp);
\draw[->] (T)           -- ++(2.5,0) 
                        |- node[txt,anchor=west,pos=.25,xshift=.5em]{j = j + 1} 
                           (red.east);
\draw[->] (red.6)       |- node[txt,anchor=west,pos=.25,xshift=.5em]{i = i + 1}
                          (v.east);
\draw[->] (comp.west)   -- ++(-1.5,0) |- (red.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Illustration af \texttt{extend()}}

%\end{figure}
\end{document}

Finally, I would clean-up this code, e.g. delete at least the %\draw statements.

Thanks you so much @MS-SPO. I will study this code and try doing it more optimal next time im making an illustration:)
